# Kivy Fails on Creating APK | wget --no-check-certificate

Tags: android, python, kivy

I tried to create APK of my application with buildozer.

```
buildozer android debug
```

I made log_level 2 and I got this:

```
HTTP isteği gönderildi, cevap bekleniyor... 301 Moved Permanently
Yer: https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2 [izleyen]
python.org (python.org)[104.130.43.121]:443 bağlanılıyor... bağlantı kuruldu.
HATA: python.org sertifikası doğrulanamıyor. `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA' tarafından sağlanmış: Yerel olarak sağlayıcının kimliği doğrulanamaıyor.
python.org adresine güvenliği gözardı ederek bağlanmak için `--no-check-certificate' seçeneğini kullanın.
```

It says it cannot verify the certificate so it wants me to use --no-check-certificate argument. It seems buildozer script has used wget to download Python 2 from server, but could not use --no-check-certificate so I got this error.

I looked for some solutions, it is widely said to install cython 0.20, but that version is already installed. I also tried to use it with **su**, but it started the download from the beginning.

**Additional Information:** I also installed buildozer to my virtualenv. I wonder if I get rid of this problem if I install buildozer globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer and I found it necessary to share it at here since I could not find any possible duplicate in the same or similiar context.

Create a ".wgetrc" file in your home folder and open it with a text editor. Edit and save:

```
check_certificate = off
```

And wget will not check for any SSL certificate. But I don't know if it's a safe way to do this.